# Storing login token in react and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, session-storage, mobx-react

I have a typescript React app and I have a singleton DataStore.ts class that allows my React app to connect to my REST backend. The DataStore class handles everything having to do with the backend: login, logout, getting/setting/updating data etc. It uses MOBX for global state storage, ie any server data that I need to store is just assigned to @observable member variables in my DataStore class. When I login, my backend provides a token for subsequent API calls, and I store that token in the DataStore instance.

What problems are caused by just storing the token as a member variable in my DataStore object. It seems most people store the token in sessionStorage, but I'm not quite sure why this is better than storing it the way I'm storing it. Does my DataStore instance go away if someone refreshes the browser tab? Please explain.

Comment: Possibly, but we would need to see how your DataStore is implemented.

Comment: Well, it depends on how your DataStore functions, if it uses some persistent storage like localStorage or sessionStorage internally, then no, the token won't be gone on refresh, otherwise, yes it will be gone since the variables where in the memory which is not persistent.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions. I added functions to my DataStore to save the token to sessionStorage upon login and remove it from sessionStorage upon logout.